# Py4JJavaError in Jupyter Notebook while using Spark RDD map function

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, rdd, py4j

While using Jupyter Notebook for creation of Spark RDD when i try to use Map() function in pyspark it gives me an Py4JJavaError.

Here is my code that i tried to run:

`squared_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x**2) result_list = squared_rdd.collect() print(result_list)`

Here is what i got an error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 5
      2 squared_rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x**2)
      4 # Example: Perform an action - collect operation to retrieve the data as a list
----> 5 result_list = squared_rdd.take(5)
      6 print(result_list)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:2836, in RDD.take(self, num)
   2833         taken += 1
   2835 p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 2836 res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   2838 items += res
   2839 partsScanned += numPartsToTry

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:2319, in SparkContext.runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
   2317 mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
   2318 assert self._jvm is not None
-> 2319 sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
   2320 return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 16) (host.docker.internal executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$1234/536824418.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
    ... 16 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2785)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2721)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$Lambda$1700/1342536174.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2720)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$Lambda$1698/1965529917.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1206)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2984)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2923)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2912)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:971)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2263)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2303)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:179)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$Lambda$1234/536824418.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1529)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:557)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Accept timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForNewConnection(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:179)
    ... 16 more
```

When i seperately run the code individually it runs but when i try to get the output by using collect() it throws me an error. Help me reoslve this problem.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.